# How do I stop out of stock items from appearing on my WooCommerce site when using the Layered Nav widget

Tags: widgets, e-commerce, plugins

WooCommerce includes a handy Layered Nav widget. This allows you to filter the catalog items based on attributes that you've set, including for variations of items (like different sizes.)

However, if you select a variation that's out of stock, it is still returned. I've been trying to alter the widget code, but it's proving extremely complicated for my little brain.

Here's the widget code: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/widgets/widget-layered_nav.php

If anyone could provide any pointers, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: isn't there a setting in wooCommerce that allows you to not show an item if it is out of stock? I do believe there is. I would start in the settings for the theme rather than trying to alter the code.

Comment: There is (Out of stock visibility), but WooCommerce doesn't obey it when showing results from the Layered Nav widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code was for WooCoommerce 1.x - it's highly unlikely that it will work on any recent version, and I'd highly encourage you **not to bother trying to use it**. I'd also strongly recommend that you **don't** downgrade to WooCommerce 1.x in order to use this code.

---

It's not easy, but a colleague and I did it.

Some of this is specific to our use case, and it will not be very performant on larger catalogues, but it technically works. As there's not way of telling if this is the case before fetching the items, we display all items on a page and simply display:none on the out of stock items. Again, this is a workaround but works for our purposes.

```
function product_in_stock($post, $product) {
    if ($_GET['filtering'] == 1 && $_GET['filter_size'] > 0 ) {
        $STOCK = FALSE;
        $slugmap = array();
        $attribs = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $terms = get_terms( sanitize_title( 'pa_size' ));
        if($terms)foreach($terms as $term)$slugmap[$term->slug]=$term->term_id;
        $available = $product->get_available_variations();
        if($available)foreach($available as $instockitem){
            if(isset($instockitem["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"])){
                if(isset($slugmap[$instockitem["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"]])){
                    if($slugmap[$instockitem["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"]] == $_GET["filter_size"]){
                        $STOCK = TRUE;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $STOCK;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function check_if_out_of_stock(){
    global $post,$product;
    $stock = product_in_stock($post,$product);

    $output = '<div class="';
    $output .= $stock?"instock":"outofstock";
    $output .= '">';
    echo $output;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'check_if_out_of_stock');

function close_out_of_stock(){
    echo "</div>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'close_out_of_stock');
```

Comment: This code does **not** work anymore - see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138140/how-do-i-stop-out-of-stock-variation-items-from-appearing-on-my-woocommerce-si).

Comment: doesnot work anymore with wp 5.4

Answer (score 0):

// Out of stock for general woocommerce - might help someone

```
            function product_in_stock($post, $product) {

                    if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {

                        $STOCK = TRUE;
                        return $STOCK;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function check_if_out_of_stock(){
                global $post,$product;
                $stock = product_in_stock($post,$product);

                $output = '<div class="';
                $output .= $stock?"instock":"outofstock";
                $output .= '">';
                echo $output;
            }

            add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'check_if_out_of_stock');

            function close_out_of_stock(){
                echo "</div>";
            }
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing here, and why this will/should work. Your code makes not much sense to me - at least uncommented/unexplained.

Comment: This wraps a div with a class of outofstock or instock around the product. You can then style each of these classes. Eg. .outofstock {display:none;}